Asset Validation failed or Invalid Executable in Xcode 16 when uploading the iOS builds
I have a .NET MAUI Application, and I am trying to upload the build in Xcode 16, getting the below error.

Invalid Executable: The executable file ‘YourAppName.app/Frameworks/TOCropViewController.framework/TOCropViewController’ contains bitcode.


Can you suggest any solution for the above issue.

Have you tried Publish an iOS app for App Store distribution?

Do you use any third-party NuGet or  library?

The issue was due to an image cropper NuGet package that was not being used in the app.
I removed it, and now there are no issues with pushing the build.
